# Gaussian is conjugate of Gaussian?

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, bayesian, normal-distribution, conjugate-prior

Someone told me that the Gaussian distribution is conjugate to the Gaussian distribution because a Gaussian times a Gaussian would still be Gaussian distribution.

Why is that ? Say the following situation: $X\sim N(\mu_x,\sigma^2_{x})$ , $Y\sim N(\mu_y,\sigma^2_{y})$

Would a new variable, $Z=XY$ be normally distributed?

Comment: Beware! The expression $Z=XY$ means to take the product of the *random variables* $X$ and $Y$, not their densities (and the distribution of such a $Z$ would *not* be Gaussian, but quite peaked); $f_X(z)f_Y(z)$ is the product of the densities, and that is proportional to another Gaussian. It's the second thing you would be looking at when talking about conjugacy.

Comment: Would you mind to comment on that ? what do you mean by $f_x(z)$?

Comment: $f_X(z)$ is the density of the random variable $X$ evaluated at $z$. The product of the value taken by the two densities at $z$ is the thing that is proportional to another Gaussian density (i.e. you need the product of the densities, *not* the density of the product).

Answer (score 14):

If we take your question to mean whether the product of the *densities* are Gaussian, then the answer is "yes" ([P.A. Bromiley. Tina Memo No. 2003-003. "Products and Convolutions of Gaussian Probability Density Functions."](http://www.lucamartino.altervista.org/2003-003.pdf)).

## Here's a simple derivation.

Take $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ to be two normal densities with means $\mu_f$ and $\mu_g$ and **precisions** $$\tau_f=\frac{1}{2\sigma_f^2}$$ and $$\tau_g=\frac{1}{2\sigma_g^2}.$$

The logarithm of the product $f(x)g(x)$ is the sum of the logarithms.
$$
\begin{align}
\log f(x) + \log g(x) &= \log C -  \tau_f(x -\mu_f)^2 - \tau_g(x-\mu_g)^2 \\
&= \log C - (\tau_f+\tau_g)\left[2x^2 - 2x(\mu_f+ \mu_g) + \mu_f^2 + \mu_g^2 \right]
\end{align}
$$

The sum of quadratics is quadratic, so we know that this is a normal density without doing any more work. Specifically, inspection gives the mean and precisions.

## Here's a longer, more tedious derivation.

Take $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ to be two normal densities with means $\mu_f$ and $\mu_g$ and variances $\sigma_f^2$ and $\sigma_g^2$.

The product is $$f(x)g(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma_f\sigma_g}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu_f)^2}{2\sigma_f^2}-\frac{(x-\mu_g)^2}{2\sigma_g^2}\right).$$

Denote $\beta=\frac{(x-\mu_f)^2}{2\sigma_f^2}+\frac{(x-\mu_g)^2}{2\sigma_g^2}.$

Expand:
$$\beta=\frac{(\sigma^2_f+\sigma^2_g)x^2-2(\mu_f\sigma^2_g+\mu_g\sigma^2_f)x+
\mu^2_f\sigma^2_g+\mu^2_g\sigma^2_f}
{2\sigma^2_f\sigma^2_g}$$

Divide through by the coefficient of the leading power, $x^2$:
$$\beta=\frac{x^2-2\frac{\mu_f\sigma^2_g+\mu_g\sigma^2_f}{\sigma^2_f+\sigma^2_g}x+\frac{\mu_f^2\sigma^2_g+\mu^2_g\sigma^2_f}{\sigma^2_f+\sigma^2_g}}{2\frac{\sigma^2_f\sigma^2_g}{\sigma^2_f+\sigma^2_g}}$$

This is quadratic in $x$, so it's Gaussian. But if we continue with the algebra, we can make this even more explicit.

Completing the square is a procedure that expresses a quadratic in $x$ with the form $(x+b)^2$. We can apply this here. If $\epsilon$ is the term required to complete the square in $\beta$,
$$\epsilon=\frac{\left(\frac{\mu_f\sigma^2+\mu_g\sigma^2_f}{\sigma_f^2+\sigma_g^2}\right)-
\left(\frac{\mu_f\sigma_g^2+\mu_g\sigma_f^2}{\sigma_f^2+\sigma_g^2}\right)}{2\frac{\sigma^2_f\sigma^2_g}{\sigma^2_f+\sigma^2_g}}=0.$$

We add this to $\beta$. Its value is zero, so it does not change the value of $\beta$ for the same reason that $5+0=5$. However, it does allow us to re-express $\beta:$

$$\begin{align}
\beta&=\frac{x^2-
2\frac{\mu_f\sigma^2_g+\mu_g\sigma^2_f}{\sigma^2_f+\sigma^2_g}x+
\left(\frac{\mu_f^2\sigma^2_g+\mu^2_g\sigma^2_f}
{\sigma^2_f+\sigma^2_g}\right)^2}
{2\frac{\sigma^2_f\sigma^2_g}{\sigma^2_f+\sigma^2_g}}+
\frac{\left(\frac{\mu_f\sigma^2+\mu_g\sigma^2_f}{\sigma_f^2+\sigma_g^2}\right)-
\left(\frac{\mu_f\sigma_g^2+\mu_g\sigma_f^2}{\sigma_f^2+\sigma_g^2}\right)^2}{2\frac{\sigma^2_f\sigma^2_g}{\sigma^2_f+\sigma^2_g}}\\
&=\frac{\left(x- \frac{\mu_f\sigma_g^2+\mu_g\sigma_f^2}
           {\sigma_f^2+\sigma_g^2}\right)^2}
       {2\frac{\sigma^2_f\sigma_g^2}
        {\sigma_f^2+\sigma_g^2}}+
  \frac{(\mu_f-\mu_g)^2}{2(\sigma_f^2+\sigma_g^2)}\\
&=\frac{(x-\mu_{fg})^2}{2\sigma^2_{fg}}+\frac{(\mu_f-\mu_g)^2}{2(\sigma_f^2+\sigma_g^2)}
\end{align}$$

Where
$$\mu_{fg}=\frac{\mu_f\sigma^2_g+\mu_g\sigma_f^2}{\sigma_f^2+\sigma_g^2}$$
and
$$\sigma_{fg}^2=\frac{\sigma_f^2\sigma_g^2}{\sigma_f^2+\sigma_g^2}.$$

So
$$f(x)g(s)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma_f\sigma_g}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu_{fg})^2}{2\sigma^2_{fg}}\right)\exp\left(\frac{(\mu_f-\mu_g)^2}{2(\sigma_f^2+\sigma_g^2)}\right)$$
This can be written as a scaled Gaussian PDF:
$$f(x)g(x)=\frac{S_{fg}}{\sigma_{fg}\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu_{fg})^2}{2\sigma_{fg}^2}\right)$$
where
$$
S_{fg}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(\sigma_f^2+\sigma_g^2)}}\exp\left(-\frac{(\mu_f-\mu_g)^2}{2(\sigma_f^2+\sigma_g^2)}\right)
$$

Note that the scaling constant is also a Gaussian function of the two means and two variances.

The product of two Gaussian densities is Gaussian, and the Gaussian is a member of the exponential family. Therefore, the Gaussian is conjugate prior to itself by the definition of conjugacy.

Comment: The algebra hugely simplifies when you parameterize the Normal distributions in terms of the mean and the *precision* and work with the logarithm of the unnormalized densities.  It is immediate that the log product is quadratic (it's a sum of quadratics) and one can find the associated precision and mean by inspection.  That would reduce this post to two lines of algebra.

Answer (score 7):

Because a comment of mine about obtaining a simple answer seems to have generated interest, here are the details.

#### Restatement of the question

The question asks whether the product of two Normal *density* functions determines a Normally distributed variable.  In the notation of the question, these functions have the form

$$f(x; \mu, \sigma) = C(\mu,\sigma)\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right)= C(\mu,\sigma)\exp\left(-\tau(\sigma)^2\left(x-\mu\right)^2\right)$$

where $C(\mu,\sigma)$ is the normalizing constant (a number determined by the need to make $f(x;\mu,\sigma)\,\mathrm{d}x$ integrate to unity) and $$\tau(\sigma)^2 = \frac{1}{2\sigma^2}.$$

$2\tau(\sigma)^2$ (the reciprocal of the variance) is known as the [precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_(statistics)).

#### Use of the logarithm to simplify the analysis

Because $f$ is always positive, we may work with its logarithm, which is a quadratic function of $x:$

$$\log f(x;\mu,\sigma) = A(\mu,\sigma) - \tau(\sigma)^2(x-\mu)^2\tag{*}$$

(where, evidently, $A(\mu,\sigma) = \log(C(\mu,\sigma))$).

Notice that this expression describes *all* nondegenerate quadratic functions of $x$ with negative leading coefficient.  That is, given any quadratic $Q(x) = -ax^2 + 2bx + c,$ we may find $\mu,$ $\sigma,$ and a constant (to play the role of $A(\mu,\sigma)$) in which $Q$ is expressed in the form $(*).$  Finding $\mu$ and $\sigma$ given $a,b,c$ is called *completing the square.*  However, *the details will not matter here,* so I leave it to the interested reader to work out the formulas (which is a straightforward exercise in elementary algebra).

Conversely (by definition of Normal distributions), *any distribution with a log density function that can be written in this form (and is defined for all real numbers) is a Normal distribution.*  Let's memorialize this characterization by highlighting it:

> Any density function $f$ that is (a) defined for all real numbers and (b) whose logarithm is a quadratic function of its argument describes a Normal distribution.

#### Solution

Recall that the logarithm of a product is the sum of the logarithms.  Thus, the question comes down to this:

> Is the sum of two quadratic functions quadratic?

**Trivially, yes, because by the rules of polynomial addition,**

$$(-a_1 x^2 + 2b_1 x + c_1) + (-a_2 x^2 + 2b_2 x + c_2) = -(a_1+a_2)x^2 + 2(b_1+b_2)x + (c_1+c_2),$$

*QED.*

We can go further, though: it is of interest to identify *which* Normal distribution occurs.  For this, the notation of the question will be convenient.  The preceding calculation is now written

$$\begin{aligned}
\left(A(\mu_x,\sigma_x)-\tau(\sigma_x)^2 (x-\mu_x)^2\right) + \left(A(\mu_y,\sigma_y)-\tau(\sigma_y)^2 (x-\mu_y)^2\right) \\
= A(\mu,\sigma)-\tau(\sigma)^2 (x-\mu)^2 \end{aligned}$$

where $\sigma^2$ is the variance of the result, $\mu$ is its mean, and $A(\mu,\sigma)$ is the logarithm of its normalizing constant.

My point is that **we can solve this problem by inspection.**  This is a math-speak term for saying you don't have to write anything down because you can pick out appropriate polynomial coefficients just by looking.  To wit,

1. The coefficient of $x^2$ must be the sum of its coefficients on the left hand side, giving $$\tau(\sigma)^2 = \tau(\sigma_x)^2 + \tau(\sigma_y)^2.\tag{1}$$
2. The coefficient of $x$ must be the sum of its coefficients on the left hand side.  This requires slightly greater perception: namely, recognizing that the coefficient of $x$ in the square $(x-\mu)^2$ is $-2\mu.$  Thus, $$2\tau(\sigma)^2 \mu = 2\tau(\sigma_x)^2\mu_x +2\tau(\sigma_y)^2\mu_y.$$

**Here, then, is the second place where we actually have to do some algebra: solve this equation for $\mu.$**  Again, the solution is by inspection (because the equation is so simple), and we can simplify it using $(1)$ above:

$$\mu = \frac{2\tau(\sigma_x)^2\mu_x + 2\tau(\sigma_y)^2\mu_y}{2\tau(\sigma)^2} = \frac{2\tau(\sigma_x)^2\mu_x  + 2\tau(\sigma_y)^2\mu_y}{2\tau(\sigma_x)^2 + 2\tau(\sigma_y)^2}.\tag{2}$$

The factors of $2\tau(\ )^2$ are the *precisions* of the distributions (*q.v.*), enabling us to characterize the results $(1)$ and $(2)$ in a simple, memorable fashion:

> When multiplying two Normal densities, *precisions add* (just double both sides of equation $(1)$) and *the mean is the precision-weighted average of the means* (equation $(2)$).

---

The two highlighted equations--the first simplifying the sum of quadratics and the second solving a simple linear equation in one unknown--constitute the "two lines of algebra" I mentioned in my comment.