# If both prior and likelihood are Gaussian what can we say about the posterior?

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, likelihood, conjugate-prior

If X is a random variable that has Gaussian prior and Gaussian likelihood. What can be inferred about the posterior?

As posterior is proporional to prior*likelihood which are Gaussians, the posterior should also be Gaussians. But I have struggles deriving it.

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our tour, which has information for new users. Please add the [self-study] tag and read its wiki. Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.  If this is self-study rather than homework, let us know, and... it's still a good idea to show us what you've tried or explain specifically what you don't understand.

Comment: @Alex, do you mean to say "As posterior is proportional to prior*likelihood" ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [posterior Gaussian distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/203953/posterior-gaussian-distribution) although we can probably reverse the duplicate and the target

Comment: Another promising target is my own answer, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/124623/gaussian-is-conjugate-of-gaussian/124625#124625

Comment: @curious_dan : Bayes' formula says the posterior density is proportional to the product of the prior density and the likelihood function. Do you know what the prior density and the likelihood function are?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The exponents in the prior density and the likelihood are added to each other
\begin{align}
& \frac{(\mu-\mu_0)^2}{\tau^2} + \frac{(\overline x - \mu)^2}{\sigma^2/n} \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac{(\sigma^2/n)(\mu-\mu_0)^2 + \tau^2(\overline x - \mu)^2}{\sigma^2\tau^2/n} \tag 1
\end{align}
Now let's work on the numerator:
$$
((\sigma^2/n)+\tau^2) \left(\mu^2 - 2\left(\mu_0\frac{\sigma^2}n + \overline x \tau^2\right)\mu + \text{“constant''} \right) \tag 2
$$
where “constant” means **not depending on $\mu$.**

Now **complete the square:**
$$
\left(\mu - \left(\mu_0 \frac{\sigma^2}n + \overline x \tau^2\right)\right)^2 + \text{“constant''}
$$
(where this “constant” will differ from the earlier one, but it just becomes part of the normalizing constant).

So the posterior density is $$ \text{constant} \times \exp\Big( 
\text{negative constant} \times (\mu-\text{something})^2 \Big).$$

In other words, the posterior is Gaussian.

The posterior mean is a weighted average of the prior mean $\mu_0$ and the sample mean $\overline x,$ with weights proportional to the reciprocals of the variances $\tau^2$ (for the prior) and $\sigma^2/n$ (for the sample mean).

Comment: However, just to note that this works when $\mu$ enters linearly in the quadratic form in the Gaussian density of $[X \mid \mu]$. If we have ${x_i - f(\mu)}$, with $f(\cdot)$ nonlinear, then we don’t get a Gaussian posterior.

Comment: @Henry : Yes. Fixed. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy could you elaborate more on what is exactly the value of these constants, because they should follow the form of a Gaussian distribution.

Comment: @MosabShaheen : I will edit the answer somewhat before commenting further here.

Comment: Now I'm thinking my answer above could use some further editing. The answer I considered writing here in comments (and probably still will write) to Mossab Shaheen's request will still probably be essentially what I first thought of writing here.

Comment: @MichaelHardy you can write it anywhere (preferably together with the answer). Just I want to know what these constraints equal.

Comment: @MosabShaheen : The numerator is $$(\sigma^2/n)(\mu-\mu_0)^2 + \tau^2(\overline x - \mu)^2.$$ By routine algebra we see that that is a quadratic polynomial in $\mu{:}$ $$ ((\sigma^2/n)+\tau^2) \left(\mu^2 - 2\left( \frac{\mu_0 \frac{\sigma^2} n
+ \overline x \tau^2}{\frac{\sigma^2}n + \tau^2} \right)\mu + {} \underbrace{ \frac{ \frac{\sigma^2} n \mu_0^2
+ \tau^2\overline x^2}{\frac{\sigma^2}n + \tau^2} } \right) $$
The part above the $\underbrace{\text{underbrace}}$
does not depend on $\mu;$ thus it is a ``constant.'' To be continued$\,\ldots\qquad\qquad\qquad$

Comment: @MosabShaheen : Now we need to work on the part in the parentheses:
$$
\mu^2 - 2\left( \frac{ \mu_0 \frac{\sigma^2} n
+ \overline x \tau^2}{\frac{\sigma^2} n + \tau^2} \right)\mu + {}
\underbrace{ \frac{ \frac{\sigma^2} n \mu_0^2
+ \tau^2\overline x^2}{\frac{\sigma^2}n + \tau^2} }
$$ To be continued$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: @MosabShaheen : First, complete the square:
$$
\overbrace{ \left( \mu^2 - 2 \left( \frac{ \mu_0 \frac{\sigma^2} n
+ \overline x \tau^2}{\frac{\sigma^2} n + \tau^2} \right) \mu
+ \left( \frac{ \mu_0 \frac{\sigma^2} n
+ \overline x \tau^2}{\frac{\sigma^2} n + \tau^2} \right)^2 \right) }^\text{the complete square}
{} + \underbrace{
\frac{ \frac{\sigma^2} n \mu_0^2
+ \tau^2\overline x^2}{\frac{\sigma^2}n + \tau^2}
- \left( \frac{ \mu_0 \frac{\sigma^2} n
+ \overline x \tau^2}{\frac{\sigma^2} n + \tau^2} \right)^2
}_\text{the ``constant'' not depending on $\mu$}
$$ To be continued...

Comment: @MosabShaheen : Now do the first thing you always do immediately after completing the square:
$$
\underbrace{\left( \mu
- \left( \frac{\mu_0\frac{\sigma^2}n
+ \overline x \tau^2}{\frac{\sigma^2} n + \tau^2} \right) \right)^2
}_\text{the complete square}
{} + \underbrace{ \frac{ \frac{\sigma^2} n \mu_0^2
+ \tau^2\overline x^2}{\frac{\sigma^2}n + \tau^2}
- \left( \frac{ \mu_0 \frac{\sigma^2} n
+ \overline x \tau^2}{\frac{\sigma^2} n + \tau^2} \right)^2
}_\text{the ``constant'' not depending on $\mu$}
$$ To be continued$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: @MosabShaheen : So the product of the prior and the likelihood is proportional (as a function of $\mu$) to
$$
\begin{align}
& \exp\left( -\frac1{2\cdot\text{variance}}
\left( \mu - \left( \frac{ \mu_0\frac{\sigma^2}n
+ \overline x \tau^2}{\frac{\sigma^2} n
+ \tau^2} \right) \right)^2 \right) \\{} \\
& \qquad {} \times \exp\left( \begin{array}{l} \text{constant not} \\
\text{depending on $\mu$} \end{array} \right)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: @MosabShaheen : The posterior expected value is therefore $$ \frac{ \mu_0\frac{\sigma^2}n
+ \overline x \tau^2}{\frac{\sigma^2} n
+ \tau^2} = \frac{\frac{\mu_0}{\tau^2} + \frac{n\overline x}{\sigma^2} }{\frac1{\tau^2} + \frac n{\sigma^2}}. $$ Thus it is a weight average of the prior mean $\mu_0$ and the sample mean $\overline x,$ with weight proportional to the reciprocals of the prior variance $\tau^2$ and the sample variance $\sigma^2/n.$ The weight given to the sample mean $\overline x$ grows as the sample size $n$ grows, as on would expect.

Comment: @MosabShaheen : As the sample size $n$ grows, the weight $$ \frac{\frac 1{\tau^2}}{\frac1{\tau^2} + \frac n{\sigma^2}}$$ given to the prior mean approaches $0$ and the weight $$ \frac{\frac n{\sigma^2}}{\frac1{\tau^2} + \frac n{\sigma^2}}$$ given to the sample mean approaches $1. \qquad$