# How can the marginal distribution be derived from conjugate Gaussians?

Tags: marginal-distribution, conjugate-prior

In [An Introduction to Empirical Bayes Data Analysis](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2682801) by George Casella (1985), it is given that
\begin{align}
x|\theta &\sim N(\theta,\sigma^2) \\
\theta &\sim N(\mu,\tau^2)
\end{align}
and since the [Gaussian distribution is conjugate to itself](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/124623/gaussian-is-conjugate-of-gaussian), then the posterior distribution is
$$
\theta|x \sim N\left(\frac{\theta\tau^2 + \mu\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+\tau^2},\frac{\sigma^2\tau^2}{\sigma^2 + \tau^2}\right)
$$
However, it is also mentioned in the paper that
$$
x \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2 + \tau^2)
$$
I am not sure how $p(x)$ was derived here. Was this derived by re-arranging Bayes rule such that
$$
p(x) = \frac{p(x|\theta)p(\theta)}{p(\theta|x)}
$$

Comment: The standard (and tedious) algebraic manipulations the author refers to rely on conjugacy of Gaussians, and also on completing the square in $\theta_i$.

Comment: @microhaus thanks for the comment. I've edited my question to focus on a much smaller part of it.

Comment: Hi: if you can get your hands on arnold zellner's bayesian text, I'm pretty sure that all of the details will be contained in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unconditional distribution of $x$ is also normal (you can see the full proof [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/124623/gaussian-is-conjugate-of-gaussian)) and what you need to do is finding its parameters. The Bayes theorem would solve it, but it isn't mandatory (and neither is the posterior distribution). You can have it simply by using the laws of total expectation and total variance:

$$E[x]=E[E[x|\theta]]=E[\theta]=\mu$$

$$Var(x)=E[Var(x|\theta)]+Var(E[x|\theta])=E[\sigma^2]+Var(\theta)=\sigma^2+\tau^2$$

Comment: Nice one! How did you know that the prior would also be normal though? Is it because $p(x) \propto p(x|\theta)p(\theta)$?

Comment: I knew the prior $p(\theta)$ is normal because you wrote it :)

Comment: Actually, I was referring to $p(x)$. Thanks for the edit!